# how to fix mysql version in my maven project

Tags: java, mysql, maven

I have downloaded wampp server which indicates that my MySQL version is 5.7.24 but whenever I try to specify that version in my maven project (in pom.xml) it shows that I'm unable to use that version:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because mysql-connector-java and MySQL don't need to be same version.

If you are using Java 8 then you should probably go with newest 8.X.X version of mysql-connector-java, it supports 5.7 version of MySQL as well as higher versions.

Current newest version:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.18</version>
</dependency>
```

You can always check newest version on mvnrepository:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Mora about version support can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html)

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL Connector/J hasn't such a fine versioning on [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java).

You usually are pretty fine with using a newer version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.18</version>
</dependency>
```